# Why isn't my object being added to my array?

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, object

I have a ManagementCompany data manager class that stores information about various properties in a Property (a class I defined) type array called properties[]. One of the methods of the class is meant to add properties to that array, and is called addProperty(Property p). It should take the given property and add it to the array in the first available space, if there is any (as seen here:)

```
Property[] properties = new Property[5];

public int addProperty(Property p) {
        if (isArrayFull())                              //Method returns true if there is no space, false otherwise                             
            return -1;
        else if (p == null)                             //Make sure p is valid          
            return -2;                                          
        for (int i = 0 ; i < properties.length; i++) {          //Loop through all elements in the array
            if (properties[i] == null) {                          //If the space is empty
                properties[i] = new Property(p);                     //Assign a new property to it
                return i;                                            //Return the index of the new property
            }
        }
        return -10;                                       //Should never happen, but need it to compile                                 
}
```

However, when I create and add properties to the array, only the first property is added. After the first property is added, the program doesn't continue adding to the first available space, instead, it seems to just ignore them. It doesn't replace the first one, and doesn't add it to the array (which is initialized to a length of 5). Any suggestions as to why?

Tests I'm running on it:

```
ManagementCompany mgmCmp = new ManagementCompany();


Property p1 = new Property("Property 1");
mgmCmp.addProperty(p1);


Property p2 = new Property("Property 2");
mgmCmp.addProperty(p2);

System.out.println(mgmCmp.toString());
```

The result is: 
Property 1  null null null null

Comment: You need to show us a proper [mre] - something containing all the relevant code that we can test. Maybe your `isArrayFull()` is wrong, maybe your array is not initialized properly - we can't tell from what you have shown us.

Comment: Please provide the calling method
it seems the addProperty method is being called only once
do you print the array or each result of addProperty?

Comment: I added the simple tests I'm using - you'll see that I'm calling the method twice and passing it different objects each time.

Comment: can you add show isArrayFull()
and mgmCmp.toString()

Answer (score 0):

> only the first property is added... Any suggestions as to why?

Because of `return i;`. You exit the method once you've added one property.

Hope that helps

Comment: This is not a problem. Assume you have a non-null value at `properties[0]` and `properties[1] == null` is `true`, the loop will run `2` times and will return `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Found a seemingly unrelated method in another class that was causing the object not to be stored in the array. Thanks for the advice.